# OpenShift catridge using yum and augeas

Tags: openshift

What is the best way to create a custom OpenShift cartridge?
Looking at documentation and examples, I am seeing a lot of old-school compiling from source installation of the component that the cartridge needs to run.

Some examples https://www.openshift.com/blogs/lightweight-http-serving-using-nginx-on-openshift https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-diy-nginx-php/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/build_nginx https://github.com/razorinc/redis-openshift-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/build and a ton of others are compiling from source..

I need to create some custom cartridges on my project, but doing it this way feels wrong.
Is there any reason I cant use yum and puppet/augeas to do the building, instead of curl, make and sed?

Or is this the best practice? In that case, why are we doing this 2000 style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do my best to explain this the best way I can. Feel free to let me know If I need to explain anything in more detail.

I'm assuming you're creating a custom binary cartridge (ie. you're creating a language cartridge such as ruby, python, etc.). Since none of the nodes have that binary installed on the system the custom cartridge you're creating will need to provide that binary and its libraries.

When you install a package with yum its going to install items in several different directories (/etc, /usr/, /var, etc). Since you're creating cartridge that will be copied over to several nodes you'll need to package all these items in a way that can be copied over to a node and then be executed without having to install them to the system.

As for doc's, I would suggest taking a look at these:

https://www.openshift.com/developers/download-cartridges
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/new-openshift-cartridge-format-part-1
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/new-openshift-cartridge-format-part-2